# Upload file with input type file in form and c# HttpPostedFile

Tags: c#, html, razor

I try to user an input type file to upload a file but my code don't work.

the variable "filePosted" stay to null value.

My code :

HTML :

```
    <form method="post" name="gestionmembre" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @using (Html.BeginForm()){
                <label class="lmembre" for="nom">Nom:</label>@Html.TextBox("nom")<br />
                <label class="lmembre" for="prenom">Prénom:</label>@Html.TextBox("prenom", Request["Prenom"])<br />
                <label class="lmembre" for="mail">Mail:</label>@Html.TextBox("mail", Request["mail"])<br />
                <label class="lmembre" for="photo">Photo:</label><input id="phototelecharge" type="file" name="photo" value="Télécharger photo"/> <br /> 
                <div class="errorform">@Html.ValidationSummary()</div>
                <input id="ajoutmembre" type="submit" name="boutonmembre" value="Ajouter"/>
    }
    </form>
```

I don't know if I have to put this atributes in form tag (method runat enctype).

now, in the controler, in block to receive form values, I put :

```
        else if (Request["boutonmembre"] == "Ajouter")
        {
            //Traitement de l'upload de l'image

            HttpPostedFile filePosted;
            filePosted = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["phototelecharge"];


            if (filePosted != null && filePosted.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileNameApplication = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePosted.FileName);
                string fileExtensionApplication = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileNameApplication);

                // generating a random guid for a new file at server for the uploaded file
                string newFile = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtensionApplication;
                // getting a valid server path to save
                string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("uploads"), newFile);

                if (fileNameApplication != String.Empty)
                {
                    filePosted.SaveAs(filePath);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is in :

```
            filePosted = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["phototelecharge"];
```

The variable fileposted is null.

In the webpage, I select a file fro a disk and the path of the file is realy indicate in the textbox.

Tks for help me.
David

Comment: `<form method="post" name="gestionmembre" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @using (Html.BeginForm()){` Is this a typo? If not remove the <Form> tag and just use `@using (Html.BeginForm("action","controller", FormMethod.Post))`

Comment: Also add a parameter to your action `(HttpPostedFIleBase  phototelecharge)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example

Controller

```
namespace stackoverflow.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    { 
       public ActionResult PostFile(HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
       {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            return View();
       } 
    }
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div id="postdata">
        <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myFile" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: hi, I just added a comment, tks

Comment: Not sure I understood correctly. Lets take this on a chat.